# Python: Got dict_keys and str instead of str

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have been working with certain Json File and I want to store all key in certain list but I am getting as follows

```
[
"dict_keys(['Agricultural Development Bank Ltd.'])",
"dict_keys(['Bank of Kathmandu Limited'])",
"dict_keys(['Best Finance Company Ltd.'])",
"dict_keys(['Central Finance Ltd'])",
"dict_keys(['Century Commercial Bank Limited'])",]
```

how do I only get 'Agricultural Development Bank Ltd.'?

here is code I worked on

a small part of json is here

```
data = [
    {
        "Agricultural Development Bank Ltd.": [
            "Palpa (Rampur) Branch",
            "Tinpaini Branch"]}, {
        "Bank of Kathmandu Limited": [
            "Palpa (Rampur) Branch",
            "Tinpaini Branch"]}]
       




import json

all_branch = []
for datas in data:
    all_branch.append(str(datas.keys()))

with open('bank_branches.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(all_branch, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

how do I get only str?

Comment: can there be more than 1 key for each dictionary in data?

Comment: yes there are about 60 keys in data

Comment: no i mean, for each of the dictionaries in the list, can there be more than 1 key. for example here `{
        "Agricultural Development Bank Ltd.": ["Palpa (Rampur) Branch",
            "Tinpaini Branch"]}`, there is only 1 key. can this single dictionary have more than 1

Comment: there can be more but not same key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for all the dictionaries with the specific key

```
json.dump([d for d in data if 'Agricultural Development Bank Ltd.' in d], f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```